# Is copying parameter considered as plagarism?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, r, xgboost, hyperparameter

So my friends and i are writing a kaggle assignment and the base code is written by me.

One of my friend use my base code(feature engineering, labeling, etc.) and put it into a loop to find the best parameter.

And the resulting parameter has 7 decimals accuracy which outperforms every other people's result.

So if we copying his parameter is it consider as cheating?

Comment: Nopes. Kaggle kernels are free to use and experiment

Comment: @Syenix the point is we are doing a final course project and we are not using kaggle kernel and the loop function i just found that it is copied from a website by my friend.

Comment: We cannot tell what is considered "cheating" or not on your coursework. In some cases sharing your code with another student would be cheating. In other cases you may be expected to collaborate. In the real world if you worked for the same company this would be expected (no point you both performing both tasks). In a learning environment you may well be expected to perform all the tasks yourself and share nothing because the point is to learn how to do the tasks. You need to ask your course supervisor.

Comment: There is a difference if this is a formal Kaggle competition with a cash prize, and not coursework. Could you please make it clear in your question which that is (use [edit])? Most Kaggle competitions ban *private* sharing, and you would be disqualified for sharing anything - code or parameters - unless they are made public to all competitors.

Comment: plagiarism is when somebody pretends to be the author of something when they're not. So strictly speaking if your friend cites you as the author of the base code then it's not plagiarism. But whether reusing somebody else's code is considered cheating or not depends on the specific rules of the competition or class.